# IntArray implementation

Tags: c++, array, homework

I need to write an `IntArray` implementation for college. I'm wondering if my code could be better and if it is efficient. In the header file are the methods listed that we need to write.

**Header file:**

```
 #ifndef INTARRAY_H_
 #define INTARRAY_H_

 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 class IntArray{
 private:
     int length;
     int * data;
public:
    IntArray(int size = 0);
    IntArray(const IntArray& other);
    IntArray& operator=(const IntArray& original);

    int getSize() const { return length; };
    int& operator[](unsigned int i);
    void resize(unsigned int size);
    void insertBefore(int value, int index);

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const IntArray& list);

    ~IntArray(){ delete[] data; };

 };
 #endif
```

**Cpp file:**

```
    IntArray::IntArray(int size){
        length = size;
        data = new int[size];
        for(int i = 0;i<size;i++){
             data[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    IntArray::IntArray(const IntArray& other){
        length = other.length;
        data  = new int[length];
        for(int i =0;i<length;i++){
        data[i] = other.data[i];
        }
    }

IntArray& IntArray::operator=(const IntArray& other){
    if(this = &other){
        return *this;
    }
    length = other.length;
    data = new int[length];
    for(int i = 0; i <length;i++){
        data[i] = other[i];
    }
    return *this;
}
void IntArray::resize(unsigned size){
      if (size <= length){
        length = size;
        return;
     }
     int * temparr = new int[size];
     // copy data
     for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i){
        temparr[i] = data[i];
     }
     delete [] data;
     data = temparr;
     length = size;
}

int& IntArray::operator [](unsigned i){
    if(i >= length || i < 0){
        throw "index out of bounds";
    }
    return data[i];
 }

 void IntArray::insertBefore(int d, int index){
     if(index >= length){
         throw "index out of bounds";
     }
     resize(length + 1);
     for(int i = length -1;i>index;i--){
          data[i] = data[i-1];
     }
     data[index] = d;
 }
```

Comment: There are some critical bugs: your `resize` doesn't; the copy will happily go out of bounds and a memory leak when you destroy an instance.

Comment: You're doing an unnecessary cast from `unsigned` to `int`. `length` should be changed to `unsigned` (all values that _can't_ be negative in the real world should usually be `unsigned`).

Comment: @zenith I have/had the same opinion, but I was told Herb Sutter (and others) disagrees (https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Interactive-Panel-Ask-Us-Anything, 44:30). Note for the answer: copy constructor has memory leak (`data` isn't freed), out of bound in the assignment one and `resize` method. `this->` superfluous in `operator[]`. No check for size >= 0.

Comment: I edited the resize. @Armaghast, but if i do 'delete [] data' in copy constructor, will that not cause problems? the program needs the link,not? I also edited the operator[], is that better?

Comment: Are you sure about closing? It looks ontopic to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Main changes:**

- Assuming you keep an `int length`, check for `size >= 0` in constructor `IntArray(int size = 0);`, and in `void IntArray::insertBefore(int d, int index)`
- You thought about `delete[] data` in the destructor. However, there are other places in your code where `data` needs to be deleted: *each time you change `data`'s value, you need to deallocate what used to be pointed by data*. Ie, `delete[] data` before any `data =`

  1. You added `data = new int[length];` in the copy constructor, so you've solved the out of bound issue, but introduced a memory leak instead. You need to deallocate `data` first.
  2. Same for the assignment constructor.
  3. `resize` had an out-of-bound issue you've fixed

Code used to be:

```
void IntArray::resize(unsigned int size){
    for(int i=length; i<size; i++){
        data[i] = 0;
    }
    length = size;
}
```

(Note: you're not supposed to edit your code, or put your updated code in a separate section, at the bottom of your question)

---

**Opinion-based**

- Maybe use an unsigned type (like `std::size_t`) instead of the signed `int` for the length.

Pros:

1. You enforce the invariant "the length can only be positive"

Cons:

1. Special values (like -1 for "Index not found") will look like regular values, higher risk of underflow.
2. (see [Herb Sutter comment](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Interactive-Panel-Ask-Us-Anything) at 44:30)

---

**Other**

- Superfluous `this->` in `operator[](int index)`
- Style: pick one of `length` or `getSize()`to get the data length, but don't mix the two (Here `length` is fine, in classes where you'd like to make a check before accessing the value, `getSomething()` is better.
- Add a `const` version of `operator[](int index)`
- Don't add an extra space at the end of `operator<<` (which you removed by mistake)

---

**Going further**

It depends on the assignment.

- Optimization: Introducing capacity to reduce the number of allocations/deallocations
- Add iterators
- Add convenience methods (`bool empty() const;`, `int& front();`)
- Add typedefs like `typedef int value_type` (useful for for metaprogramming)
- Add relationship operators (at least `==` and `!=`)

---

@glampert made excellent points I forgot, check his answer.

Comment: Thanks alot, is this a good const version for the [] operator? i will update the rest of the code, thanks it was really useful !!! 
const int& operator[]  (const unsigned i)

Comment: I'd go for `const int& operator[] const (unsigned i) `, for consistency with the rest of your code.

Comment: could it be 'const int& IntArray::operator[](unsigned i)const" , otherwise c++ gives a syntax error

Comment: Yes, my mistake, `const` for the method is after the parameters.

Answer (score 2):

@Armaghast's answer is already very complete, but there are few other tidbits you should look into:

#### Don't use `using namespace` in a header file:

It exposes the whole namespace to any other file `#include`ing your header file. This pollutes the global scope and can result in name clashes. If you'd like to read a more lengthy discussion, [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) is a good starting point.

<sub>**Trivia:** I just recently noticed that the `clang` compiler has a `-Wheader-hygiene` flag, which when provided to the command line, emits a compiler warning if you use namespace in a header file.</sub>

#### Leverage the Standard Library:

I suppose since this is a class assignment, you're not allowed to use `std::vector` or [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) to manage memory for you. If this was not a class assignment, you'd use a `std::vector<int>` instead. If writing some custom data container/collection, then it would also be better to build it around an existing library class like `vector`, `list`, etc, or at the very least, use one of the standard smart pointers to manage memory for you.

That out of the way, there is one library function I think you can use that will make your code better: [`std::copy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy). Avoid using "raw loops" for copying stuff. Here you have two instances of copying the underlaying int array. For example, using `std::copy` with the `resize()` method:

```
void IntArray::resize(unsigned size) {
     ...
     int * tempArr = new int[size];
     std::copy(data, data + length, tempArr);
     delete [] data;
     data = tempArr;
     length = size;
}
```

#### Be mindful of indenting and spacing:

Right at the beginning of the implementation file, there is some extra indentation in the code. Be careful to keep indenting neat. It is one of the main things that help reading code.

Also, be careful to properly space operators and keywords. Take this `for` loop as example, from the copy constructor:

> ```
> for(int i =0;i<length;i++){
> ```

Spacing is a little messy here. It would be more pleasant to the eye if you you'd evenly space each part:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
```